# Probability distribution with random paremeters

Tags: probability-or-statistics, distributions

Is it possible to set something like this? A probability distribution with random parameters

````
p = BetaDistribution[1, 1]
count = BinomialDistribution[10, p]

(* and to calculate stuff like: *)
Expectation[count]
Probability[count == 3 \[Conditioned] p > 1/2]
```
````

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The probability distribution for `count` is

```
dist = ParameterMixtureDistribution[
  BinomialDistribution[10, p],
  p \[Distributed] BetaDistribution[1, 1]]

(* BetaBinomialDistribution[1, 1, 10] *)
```

The expected value of `count` is the [`Mean`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Mean.html) of `dist`

```
Mean[dist]

(* 5 *)

Probability[count > 1/2, count \[Distributed] dist]

(* 10/11 *)
```

Comment: It's exactly what I was looking for. Thank you, Bob!

Comment: @WHoZ if you need to draw samples from both distributions, you may also be interested in the resource function [ConditionalProductDistribution](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/ConditionalProductDistribution)